# Комбинаторика и формула для подсчета комбинаций

Tags: комбинаторика

Здравствуйте Уважаемые форумчане.

Вопрос касательно комбинаторики.

Нужна ваша помощь с поиском формулы для расчета комбинаций.

Вопрос следующий:
Имеется 5 шаров,4 куба и 3 пирамиды.

Извлекаются наугад 2 предмета.

Сколько всего имеется комбинаций при условии что все предметы в этих комбинациях будут разные(то есть шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида берутся в расчет а шар-шар,куб-куб,пирамида-пирамида в расчет не идут)?

Есть ли какая-то формула?

P.S.Я понимаю что можно найти количество сочетаний для двух предметов а затем найти количество сочетаний для двух одинаковых предметов а затем из первого результат вычесть второй,но вдруг предметов(и их типов)будет сотни,тысячи.

Их же все так не пересчитаешь.

Comment: Сами предметы одинаковы, и порядок не играет роли? Или нет? Т.е. важно, чтоб был шар, и неважно, первый или пятый? А комбинации шар-пирамида и пирамида-шар тоже неотличимы? тогда вы все три варианта и перечислили :)

Comment: Извлекаются ДВА предмета наугад
Какое количество комбинаций с учетом того что это будут два разных предмета?(то есть шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида)

Comment: Всего есть 12 предметов(5 шаров,4 куда и 3 пирамиды).Общее количество комбинаций для двух предметов из 12 равно 66.Нужно найти количество комбинаций в которых будут разные предметы.
То есть нужно найти количество комбинаций в которых будут одинаковые предметы(то есть шар-шар,куб-куб,пирамида-пирамида),а затем из общего количества комбинаций(из 66)вычесть полученный результат.
Количество комбинаций в которых будут одинаковые предметы равно 19(5*3/2);5*4/2;4*3/2)*это комбинаторика.
Далее нужно из 66 вычесть 19 получается 47.
Значит есть 47 комбинаций шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида.

Comment: Т.е. все шары разные, все кубы разные, все пирамиды разные? Ну посчитайте число комбинаций с одинаковыми предметами и вычтите. Два шара — 10, ну, и так далее...

Comment: Логично
Но что если предметов не 12 а скажем 1000 а типов этих предметов скажем 100.
Тогда расчеты будут очень долгими и сложными так как будет множество переменных.

Comment: Ну, значит, считаете для новых значений :)

Comment: Спасибо))
Хотелось бы как-то упростить расчеты)

Comment: Смотрите ответ, там это записано формулами :)

Comment: Там записано то о чем и я говорил,то что я хотел упростить)

Comment: Ну, проще чем я записал в своем ответе, у меня не получается. Даже если раскрыть скобки — будет только сложнее...

Comment: То есть можно возвести во вторую степень общее количество предметов и количество предметов в каждом типа,а затем произвести вычитание а результат разделить на количество предметов которые извлекаются?

Comment: Э нет, вы спрашивали **только о ДВУХ** извлекаемых предметах; эта формула только для этого случая.

Comment: Плохо(
А если нужно будет извлечь к примеру 3 и более предмета?
Нужна будет другая формула?

Comment: Для трёх предметов надо поставить задачу правильно. Просто так два на три заменить не получится. Там несколько разных задач в зависимости от точной формулировки.

Comment: Жаль(
А я надеялся на универсальную формулу с которой можно все посчитать
Но видимо таковой нет(

Comment: Формула есть. Их несколько. Возьмите на себя труд и поставьте задачу точно. И будет формула. Пока вы не ответили на уточняющие вопросы даже к задаче о двух предметах.

Comment: На задачу про 2 предмета уже дан ответ но Вы говорите что формула только для этого случая а значит для какого-либо другого она не подходит

Comment: Вот еще пример может быть

Comment: Имеется 5 шаров,4 куба и 3 пирамиды.

Извлекаются наугад 2 предмета.

Сколько всего имеется комбинаций при условии что все предметы в этих комбинациях будут одинаковые(то есть шар-шар,куб-куб,пирамида-пирамида)?
Понятное дело что можно найти количество комбинаций для каждого типа а затем их сложить

Comment: Но если предметов 1000 а их типов 100 то искать комбинации для каждого типа нужно будет очень долго

Comment: Поэтому я и ищу универсальную формулу,подставив значения в которую можно получить результат

Comment: Любую задачу для начала надо сформулировать точно и однозначно... При неточном ТЗ результат один — ХЗ...

Comment: Куда уже точнее?

Comment: Задача:

Дано:

10 шаров.
15 пирамид.
8 кубов.
12 призм.
6 цилиндров.
4 конуса.

Всего предметов 45(12+8+6+4+10+15).
Типов предметов 6(призмы,пирамиды,кубы,цилиндры,конуса,шары).

Условие:
Наугад извлекаются 3 предмета.
Вопрос:
Сколькое всего имеется комбинаций при условии что все 3 предмета в этих комбинациях будут разные(например шар-куб-цилиндр,призма-конус-пирамида и т.д.)?

Comment: Пойдет такая формулировка?

Comment: Так будет точнее

Comment: Задача:

Дано:

10 шаров.
15 пирамид.
8 кубов.
12 призм.
6 цилиндров.
4 конуса.

Всего предметов 45(12+8+6+4+10+15).
Типов предметов 6(призмы,пирамиды,кубы,цилиндры,конуса,шары).

Условие:
Из этих 45 предметов наугад извлекаются 3 предмета.
Вопрос: 
Сколькое всего имеется комбинаций при условии что все 3 предмета в этих комбинациях будут разные(например шар-куб-цилиндр,призма-конус-пирамида и т.д.)(то есть все 3 предмета будут разного типа)?

Answer (score 1):

Введём обозначения:

- *n* — количество видов предметов;
- *m<sub>i</sub>, 1 ≤ i ≤ n* — количество предметов конкретного вида.
- *M = ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub>* — общее количество предметов.

Предположим что порядок предметов в паре не важен. Тогда из *k* предметов можно составить *k(k - 1) / 2* пар.

Общее число пар — *M(M - 1) / 2*. Число пар одинакового типа *i* — *m<sub>i</sub>(m<sub>i</sub> - 1) / 2*. Число неодинаковых неупорядоченных пар:

*M(M - 1) / 2 - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>[m<sub>i</sub>(m<sub>i</sub> - 1) / 2]*

Если порядок предметов в паре важен, их (пар) становится в два раза больше. Из *k* предметов можно составить *k(k - 1)* пар.

Число неодинаковых упорядоченных пар:

*M(M - 1) - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub>(m<sub>i</sub> - 1)*

**P.S.** В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1560905/416121) [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) показано, как можно упростить формулы, избавившись от повторяющихся фрагментов *- 1*:

*M(M - 1) - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub>(m<sub>i</sub> - 1) = M<sup>2</sup> - M - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> - m<sub>i</sub> = M<sup>2</sup> - M - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub> =*

*= M<sup>2</sup> - M - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + M = M<sup>2</sup> - ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>n</sup>m<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>*

Comment: Может, первым членом идет произведение числа предметов, а не видов предметов? а то если видов предметов 3, и чему будет равно значение по вашей формуле? :)

Comment: Вы описали то о чем и я говорил
Нужно найти общее количество комбинаций для двух предметов и нужно найти количество комбинаций для двух предметов в которых будут одинаковые предметы,а затем из первого результата вычесть второй.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: У нас всего есть 12 предметов.
Общее количество комбинаций для двух предметов из 12 равно 66
Количество комбинаций в которых будут шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида равно 47

Comment: То есть Вы предлагает сначала найти общее количество комбинаций для двух предметов из 12 а затем найти количество комбинаций для двух предметов из каждого типа а затем из первого варианта вычесть второй?

Comment: @Илья, да, именно так.

Comment: Как бы это сейчас не прозвучало но это логично
Но
Теперь представим что предметов не 12 а скажем 1000 а типов этих предметов скажем 100
Тогда как упростить расчеты?

Comment: Ведь считать комбинации для каждых типов предметов будет очень сложно и долго
Есть ли какое-то упрощение расчетов?

Comment: @Илья, чтобы решить задачу вам нужно прочитать *n* чисел и что-то с ними сделать. Это общая постановка. Её никак нельзя упростить - *n* чисел должны быть прочитаны и собраны в результат. Формулы для решения используют *n+1* умножение, *n+1* деление и *2(n+1)* сложений/вычитаний. Это линейное число операций. Намного быстрее не сделать, такова теория сложности алгоритмов. Это всё что я могу сказать не поминая *O*-большое и прочие страсти.

Comment: Вот меня и интересовал вопрос можно ли упростить расчеты
Я сам далек от математики и поэтому пришел на форумы где люди в этой математике понимают

Answer (score 1):

Ну, или, как вариант,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

для упорядоченных пар, и делить пополам для неупорядоченных

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас — (12*12 - 3*3 - 4*4 -5*5)/2 = 47

Comment: То что можно убрать *- 1* - замечательно. Я об этом не подумал. Браво!

Comment: Эта формула на конкретную задачу а не универсальная?

Comment: Для конкретной задачи выборки 2 предметов.

Comment: Вооооот
А есть ли универсальная формула?

Comment: Да вы хоть сформулируйте, для какой задачи!

Comment: Для любой.
Задачи которые я написал это пример.
Вот если можно найти количество комбинаций для нескольких предметов из множества,то можно найти количество комбинаций,в которых будут одинаковы(или разные)предметы.

Comment: Есть комбинаторика сочетаний.
Там ищется общее количество комбинаций для нескольких предметов при извлечении из множества.
Но общее количество комбинаций будет разделено на те комбинации в которых все предметы будут одинаковые(то есть одного типа)и на те комбинации в которых будут все предметы разные(то есть разных типов)

Comment: Меня интересует как "извлечь" из общего количества комбинаций те комбинации в которых будут все предметы разные(то есть разных типов)и те комбинации в которых все предметы будут одинаковые(то есть одного типа)

Comment: Возвращаясь к задаче с двумя предметами:
Вопрос следующий: Имеется 5 шаров,4 куба и 3 пирамиды.
Извлекаются наугад 2 предмета.
Сколько всего имеется комбинаций при условии что все предметы в этих комбинациях будут разные(то есть шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида берутся в расчет а шар-шар,куб-куб,пирамида-пирамида в расчет не идут)?
Всего комбинаций будет 66.
Из них 47 комбинаций в которых будут разные предметы(то есть шар-куб,шар-пирамида,куб-пирамида).
И 19 комбинаций в которых будут одинаковые предметы(то есть шар-шар,куб-куб,пирамида-пирамида).

Comment: В этой задаче расчеты простые,так как переменных мало и их легко посчитать.
А если переменных будет 100,1000?
Тогда быстрых расчетов не получится.
А мой интерес как раз быстрые расчеты с помощью универсальной формулы,подставив значения  в которую можно получить готовый результат.
За поисками такой формулы я пришел на математические форумы.

Comment: Всё. На этом я заканчиваю с этим вопросом. Опять 25 про 1000, 100... Вас совсем не учили в школе математике и тому, как формулировать задачи? Впрочем, вопрос риторический, можете не отвечать. Мне лично эта сказочка про белого бычка надоела.